# Create a div with inline styles from database .. want to set style with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, styles, position, height

I'm using width, height, top and left properties in the database so to set them to specific div.

```
$information =<<<HEREENDS
    <div id = "randomDiv" style = "
        left: {$array[0][3]}px;
        top: {$array[0][4]}px; 
        width : {$array[0][5]}px; 
        height : {$array[0][6]}px; " > 
    </div> 
HEREENDS;
        echo $information;
```

That works BUT I'm looking for a smarter solution - is there any way I can send the array to javascript and set these styles with javascript, not inline ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to do it with javascript?

Comment: well, that's only a suggestion not necessary js

Comment: Stick with the code you have or you can try to change it to a jquery call to the server from where it can get the values and change it dynamically. Though I don't see the point from just the code you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. JavaScript allows you to access and modify style values through the [`style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.style) property. For instance:

```
var myElement = document.getElementById("randomDiv");
myElement.style.left = $array[0][3] + 'px';
myElement.style.top = $array[0][4] + 'px';
myElement.style.width = $array[0][5] + 'px';
myElement.style.height = $array[0][6] + 'px';
```

Alternatively you can put the entire style string into the style using `style.cssText`:

```
var myStyle = "left: {$array[0][3]}px;top:{$array[0][4]}px;width:{$array[0][5]}px;height : {$array[0][6]}px;";
document.getElementById("myElement").style.cssText = myStyle;
```

Do note that `style.cssText` will overwrite any previous styles on the element.

If the element doesn't already exist, there's really no reason to do this though. JavaScript will simply modify the element's `style` attribute anyway.

Comment: I wont downvote but I think the OP is trying to set the values from PHP. Which again points to my question -> why would you introduce Javascript into it then?

Comment: It would work in a similar fashion, @HanutSingh. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: I'm setting the styles with PHP, I want with js to escape the inline styles - aren't they bad practice ?

Comment: @Boriii JavaScript can't modify a stylesheet. It can only modify the element's `style` attribute. Styles changed with JavaScript *are* inline styles. It's only bad practice to include inline styles in the default page markup.